# Boost tribool question about logical operations

Tags: c++, boost

Recently, I used `boost::logic::tribool` and something was strange for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/logic/tribool.hpp"


int main()
{
    boost::logic::tribool test = true && boost::logic::indeterminate;

    if(test)
    {
     std::cout << "Executes?" << std::endl;
    }

    if (true && boost::logic::indeterminate)
    {
      std::cout << "Executes 2" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Prints `Executes` and `Executes 2`.
Why are these conditions true?
I was totally sure that AND operation with (indeterminate state, true) returns indeterminate state?

Quote from boost.org about boolean context in `if`

"returns true if the 3-state boolean is true, false otherwise"

EDIT: after comments I am adding this.
This is the most non-intuitive code I have ever read.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/logic/tribool.hpp"


int main()
{
    boost::logic::tribool test = boost::logic::tribool(true) && boost::logic::indeterminate;

    if(test)
    {
     std::cout << "This will NOT execute" << std::endl;
    }

    boost::logic::tribool second = true && boost::logic::indeterminate;

    if (second)
    {
      std::cout << "This will execute" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

EDIT2: I need to correct myself...
Anyone could explain?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/logic/tribool.hpp"

boost::logic::tribool LOL( )
{
   return    boost::logic::indeterminate;
}

int main()
{

 boost::logic::tribool LOL_RESULT = LOL();

    if (boost::logic::indeterminate)
    {
        std::cout << "IT WILL BE EXECUTED" << std::endl;
    }

    if (LOL_RESULT)
    {
      std::cout << "IT WILL NOT BE EXECUTED"   << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you get the expected output for `boost::logic::tribool test = boost::logic::tribool{true} && boost::logic::indeterminate;`

Comment: But why is it true after all?

Comment: I have no clue... out of curiosity: what do you use it for? Even without this quirk I find this `tribool` highly confusing and wouldnt want to have it in my code. I mean what could be more strange than a bool conversion such that after a `if (b) {} else if (!b) {}` you still have a `else {}` case...imho thats implicit conversion gone too far

Comment: You do not need to convince me, large codebase, you know, a lot of weird people and ideas could emerge throughout life of large project

Comment: ok, no prob, The documentation is a bit sloppy: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/logic/operator___idp51294368.html Note that it says "the result of logically ANDing the **two tribool values**, according to the following table: "  which strictly speaking excludes the `(bool,tribool)` overload

Comment: C++ doesn't know 3-valued logic, and the `if()` statement is a C++ language construct, not part of `boost::logic::tribool`. Any value that converts to something different from an integer zero, a `nullptr`, or `false` will be treated as true by the `if()` statement. And that obviously includes `boost::logic::indeterminate`.

Comment: @cmaster if I understand their [basic example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/tribool/tutorial.html#idp473654464) correctly, what you are saying is not correct. `tribool` has a super fancy bool conversion that can make both `b` and `!b`  `false` at the same time, exactly when the value is `indeterminate`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 And you are sure that the value is actually converted to `bool`? I don't know `boost::logic`, but if the statement `if(boost::logic::indeterminate) foo();` executes `foo()`, then the value cannot have been converted to `false`. Maybe it's a bug, maybe it's a pitfall, I don't know which.

Comment: @cmaster hum? `if(boost::logic::indeterminate) foo();` does not execute `foo();`. I didnt look into all details, but basically all you need is a `operator bool` and a `operator!` then you can make `if (indeterminate) {`bar();`} else if (! indeterminate) {`bar();`} else { foo();}` execute only `foo();` but not `bar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST(junk, tribool)
{
    auto v = boost::logic::indeterminate;
    GTEST_MESSAGE() << typeid(v).name();
}
```

Results in:

```
[----------] 1 test from junk
[ RUN      ] junk.tribool
[   NOTE   ] bool (__cdecl*)(class boost::logic::tribool,struct boost::logic::detail::indeterminate_t)
```

***`boost::logic::indeterminate` is a function***. So it evaluates to true.

```
TEST(junk, tribool)
{
    boost::logic::tribool test = true && boost::logic::tribool{ boost::logic::indeterminate_keyword_t() };

    if (test)
    {
        GTEST_MESSAGE() << "Executes?" << std::endl;
    }

    if (true && boost::logic::tribool{ boost::logic::indeterminate_keyword_t() })
    {
        GTEST_MESSAGE() << "Executes 2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
[----------] 1 test from junk
[ RUN      ] junk.tribool
[       OK ] junk.tribool (64970 ms)
[----------] 1 test from junk (68580 ms total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tribool is from hell:

"
The type of the 'indeterminate' keyword. This has the same type as the
function 'indeterminate' so that we can recognize when the keyword is
used.
The indeterminate function has a dual role. It's first role is
as a unary function that tells whether the tribool value is in the
"indeterminate" state.
It's second role is as a keyword
representing the indeterminate (just like "true" and "false"
represent the true and false states).
"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31411596)